# Change Tracking in SQL: NULL value when using COLUMNPROPERY

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm attempting to write a SQL query that monitors changes on a table using CHANGE TRACKING.
My query is working up to the point that I want it to also monitor which columns have changed.

I'm getting a null value on COLUMNPROPERTY which I suspect means I don't have the correct permissions. This is the first time I've attempted this type of query so would appreciate any guidance on where I've gone wrong.

Many thanks

Jodie

```
SELECT
CT.TableCalendar, 
P.txtDescription, CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK (COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID ('P'), 'txtDescription', 'ColumnID'), CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS) changeDescription, 
P.txtStartDate,
P.txtStartTime,
P.txtEndDate,
P.txtEndTime,
P.txtLocation,
P.intAllDayEvent,
P.intCategory,
P.intSubcategory,
P.txtCreatedBy, 
CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION,
CT.SYS_CHANGE_VERSION,
CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS,
CT.SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT,
U.txtFirstname,
U.txtSurname 

FROM
[dbo].[TableCalendar] AS P

RIGHT OUTER JOIN CHANGETABLE(CHANGES [dbo].[TableCalendar], @last_sync_version) AS CT ON P.TableCalendarID = CT.TableCalendarID 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TableUsers] AS U ON [txtCreatedBy] = U.txtUserCode
```

Answer (score 0):

This query was correct, unfortunately the application I was trying to track changes on was written in a way that meant if you edited one field it updated all of them in that table.